# issue converting project to FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Having successfully converted one project to FCM, I'm running into problems converting my second.  This project is unique as I prefer to keep it on targetSdkVersion 22.

This is my gradle file . . .

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myname.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':googleplayservices_lib')
    implementation files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When I try to run the project on an emulator I get . . .

> Program type already present:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.data.Freezable

I have no idea what this is about and google turns  up nothing useful.  However it appears to be caused by the firebase-core dependency because it I remove that, the project runs fine.

What might be causing this?

Comment: It's possible that there are conflicting references between the support library for version 22 and the latest Firebase core library. Have you tried using an older version of the Firebase core?

Comment: found history a maven.google.com.  Tried several older versions of core.  Same results except 'Freezable' changes to 'lifecycleDelegate' or 'Scopes' depending on version.

Comment: Got any solution? Even i have "googleplayservices_lib". When I add "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0" It gives this error